# Chrome background-color issue: "transparent" not a valid value?

Tags: google-chrome, transparent, background-color

I have a div element that needs to be hidden whenever there is no background-color set. So i've come up with this simple jquery statement:

```
$(function() {

if ($('.colorpicker').css('background-color') == 'transparent')
{
$(this).find('.colorpicker-wrapper').css('display','none');
}

});
```

everything works well in Firefox, it hides the wrapper when there's no value set for the bg-color. But in chrome and safari it doesn't seem to recognize transparent as a valid value..?

I've tried setting the value to 'null' or 'unidentified', but to no avail..

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is an inconsistency in jQuery. Normally, when no background-color is set the value is set to the empty string (`""`). See:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
return d.style.backgroundColor
```

d.style.backgroundColor will always return `""` for both firefox and chrome. But, when using the jQuery `css()` function, jQuery translates it to its default value.

I suggest using: `$('.colorpicker')[0].style.backgroundColor == ""`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome returns an rgba color of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` instead of `transparent`. Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yfjNQ/) and a method to test for it ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yfjNQ/1/)).

```
if ( /transparent|rgba\(0, 0, 0, 0\)/.test( $('.colorpicker').css('background-color') )
{
  $(this).find('.colorpicker-wrapper').css('display','none');
}
```